# Find the Adjoint Operator of Weak Derivative Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

This is a question from an example in my Functional Analysis lecture:

Let us consider the unbounded operator $A: D(A) \subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined as $Au = u'$, where $D(A):= \{ u \in L^2(\mathbb{R})| u' \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \text{ is the weak derivative of u} \}$. That is, we have $u' \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $(u', \phi) = -(u, \phi)$ for $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$.

We claim that the adjoint of $A$ is $A': D(A') \subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $A'(v) = -v'$ with $v \in D(A')$. Here is the computation given by the professor:
We have
$$
(A'v,u) = (v, Au) = (v, u') = (-v', u)
$$
where the last equality **uses integration by parts.** I am no sure why can we use integration by parts over here? Do we not need to assume some kinds of regularity to do so on $v, u$ rather than just some $L^2$ functions?

Comment: You are missing derivatives in places. E.g  $(v, u') = (-v, u)$ should be $(v, u') = (-v', u)$.

Comment: Yes you have to figure out what $D(A')$ is. I think $D(A') = D(A)$. So integration by parts can be proven by an approximation argument, using density of $C_c^{\infty}$ in $D(A) = H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.